# Correlators on the Euclidean section of a black hole

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, path-integral, correlation-functions, wick-rotation

In the standard construction of the Euclidean section of a Schwarzschild black hole, we start with the exterior metric in Schwarzschild coordinates:

$$\tag{1} ds^2 = -(1-r_s/r)dt^2 + (1-r_s/r)^{-1}dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2 $$

Letting $t=-i\tau$ and $r=r_s+\frac{\rho^2}{4r_s}$, the near-horizon metric becomes

$$\tag{2} ds^2 = \rho^2\frac{d\tau^2}{4r_s^2}+d\rho^2 + r_s^2 d\Omega^2+...$$

Finally, in order to avoid a conical singularity (which is "bad" for some reason), we identify $\tau\sim\tau+\beta$ with $\beta = 4\pi r_s$. The resulting Euclidean geometry resembles a cigar.

This is just one example of the general schematic definition of a Euclidean section: "choose coordinates (the manifold we get will depend on this choice) ->  Wick-rotate the time coordinate -> quotient the manifold to remove any conical singularities".

The idea now is to use this geometric construction to say things about QFT states. To this end, define the vacuum $|0\rangle$ as the state annihilated by the Hamiltonian $H$ (i.e. the conserved charge associated to the Killing field $\partial_t$). Then we can compute $\langle 0| \mathcal{T}\hat{\mathcal{O}}(\tau_1)...\hat{\mathcal{O}}(\tau_n)|0\rangle$, where $\hat{\mathcal{O}}(\tau)=e^{-\tau H}\hat{\mathcal{O}}e^{\tau H}$ are Heisenberg-picture operators and $\mathcal{T}$ is imaginary-time ordering.

On the other hand, we can also compute a quantity which I'll denote as $\langle \mathcal{O}(\tau_1)...\mathcal{O}(\tau_n)\rangle_{cigar}$ by inserting $\mathcal{O}(\tau_1)...\mathcal{O}(\tau_n)$ into the path integral on the cigar. **I'd like to know whether the following equality holds:**
$$\tag{3} \langle 0| \mathcal{T}\hat{\mathcal{O}}(\tau_1)...\hat{\mathcal{O}}(\tau_n)|0\rangle = \langle \mathcal{O}(\tau_1)...\mathcal{O}(\tau_n)\rangle_{cigar}.$$

I suspect that (3) is true, since it would justify the otherwise-unmotivated definition of the Euclidean section (the usual justification by appealing to Einstein's equations doesn't convince me, since we aren't doing anything involving gravity here). But I'm not sure how to prove it. Usually, we'd prepare the vacuum state via a cut path integral over the $\tau <0$ region, but on the cigar we only have a finite range of $\tau$, so I don't know how to interpret the path integral in terms of preparing the vacuum and acting with operators. I hope someone can offer a proof.

Please, in your answer, put emphasis on making the logical structure of the argument clear. I think I have all the pieces of the puzzle in my head, but they're totally jumbled up: I can't tell which things are assumptions, which things are derived, and which are just arbitrary prescriptions. Also feel free to work with a maximally extended black hole if it makes things easier.